# Given homomorphisms $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ and $\psi : G \rightarrow F$, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism, is it true that $F \simeq H \ast_G F$?

Tags: group-theory, free-product

Let $G$ be a group with two homomorphism $\phi \colon G \rightarrow H$ and 
$\psi \colon G \rightarrow F$.

If $\phi$ is an isomorphism, is it true that $F \simeq H \ast_G F$, the free product with amalgamation?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that this is not how one asks questions on MSE. Please provide context.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have a commutative diagram
$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD} G @> \phi >> H \\
@V \psi VV @VV \psi \circ \phi^{-1} V \\
F @> \operatorname{id} >> F. \end{CD} $$
Can you show that this diagram satisfies the universal property for the amalgamated product?

Comment: This does not work for infinite groups.

Comment: @Shaun Why not?  (I guess I am making the implicit assumption that the amalgamated product desired is using the given morphisms $\phi$ and $\psi$, and not possibly using some other random maps between the groups unrelated to $\phi$ or $\psi$ as your answer did.  My interpretation seems to me like the most likely intended meaning, though it *is* slightly ambiguous as stated.)

Comment: It does work, the universal property for pushout diagrams is independent of the carnidal of the objects in the category.

Comment: Because my answer is a counterexample.

Comment: The fundamental group of the Klein bottle is not $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Is not, your $\phi$ is not surjective.

Comment: Shaun's answer is a counterexample to: if $G \simeq H$ but $\phi : G \to H$ is not itself necessarily an isomorphism, then the pushout of $\phi$ and $\psi : G \to F$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $F$.  My answer is hinting at the problem: if $\phi$ is an isomorphism then the pushout of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is isomorphic to $F$.  Two different questions with a slightly subtle difference between them.

Comment: Oh, of course! Now I see it. I'm sorry.